# How to remove duplicate rows based on condition without creating temp table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, duplicates, sql-delete

Can someone help me to get a result query. I've been stuck here in a couple of hours. Sorry Im just new to SQL. I need to get the latest date(column3) without duplicates values from Column1 and Column2

```
SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3
FROM TABLE1 t1
LEFT JOIN
     TABLE2 t2
 ON t1.column1 = t2.column1
```

Table Value:

```
COLUMN1        COLUMN2        COLUMN3
VAL1             1234        2019-05-12    
VAL1             1234        2019-04-12
VAL1             1234        2019-12-12
VAL2             4321        2019-11-12
VAL2             3333        2019-12-12
VAL3             2222        2019-10-10
```

Expected Result:

```
COLUMN1         COLUMN2        COLUMN3
VAL1             1234        2019-12-12
VAL2             3333        2019-12-12
VAL3             2222        2019-10-10
```

Comment: Won't work for `'Val2'` @HoneyBadger ; as you would either need to Group on `COLUMN2` resulting in 2 rows, or apply `MAX` to `Val2`, which would return `4321` not `3333`. This needs the common `ROW_NUMBER` solution.

Comment: Hi I've used MAX() and DISTINCT, and GROUP BY but I cant get the output I've expecting. Any idea?

Comment: There are 3 duplicates for you @ArvinJohnSalandanan . All of those show you how to use a CTE/subquery and `ROW_NUMBER` to achieve this.

Comment: So I really need to use temp table in order to achieve this?

Comment: Thank you @Larnu for providing resources. Much appreciated.

Comment: *"So I really need to use temp table in order to achieve this?"* No, @ArvinJohnSalandanan , those solutions use a subquery or CTE. None of them use a Temporary Table. If you are using a solution with a Temporary Table, you can't using any of the linked duplicates answers, or accepted solutions (as none of them use one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e6155/37)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
create table MyTable (COL1 varchar(max), COL2 int,COL3 date)
insert into MyTable (COL1, COL2,COL3 )VALUES('VAL1',1234,'2019-05-12')
insert into MyTable (COL1, COL2,COL3 )VALUES('VAL1',1234,'2019-04-12')
insert into MyTable (COL1, COL2,COL3 )VALUES('VAL1',1234,'2019-12-12')
insert into MyTable (COL1, COL2,COL3 )VALUES('VAL2',4321,'2019-12-12')
insert into MyTable (COL1, COL2,COL3 )VALUES('VAL2',3333,'2019-12-12')
insert into MyTable (COL1, COL2,COL3 )VALUES('VAL3',2222,'2019-10-10')
```

**Query 1**:

```
select t.COL1,t.COL2,t.COL3
from (select m.*,
             row_number() over (partition by m.COL1
                                order by m.COL2,m.COL3 desc) as seqnum
      from MyTable m
     ) t
where t.seqnum=1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e6155/37/0)**:

```
| COL1 | COL2 |       COL3 |
|------|------|------------|
| VAL1 | 1234 | 2019-12-12 |
| VAL2 | 3333 | 2019-12-12 |
| VAL3 | 2222 | 2019-10-10 |
```